# Парсинг сайта, работающего на AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Как парсить данные, которые выводятся через *AngularJS*?

Пробовал некоторые варианты, но результат один и тот же: получаю лишь статические данные, а то что нужно, так и остается `{{man.nick}}` и в подобном роде.

Comment: Да, дело не легкое, но возможное. http://phantomjs.org/

Answer (score 1):

Есть два основных варианта:

- найти адреса подгружаемых JSON файлов в WebInspector и скачивать их через wget/curl
- прорисовывать каждый раз страницы в WebKit

Первый вариант предпочтительнее, но не всегда возможен